# Hyperlinks with target="_blank" not working after Angular 7 Migration

Tags: angular, html

I have some hyperlinks in my angular projects like this,

```
    <a href="http://host/Pages/filename.aspx" target="_blank" >Label</a>

    <a target="_blank" [routerLink]="['../otherview']" [queryParams]="
       {id:entity.id}">{{entity.id}}</a>
```

Both worked with Angular 6 project. Recently I have migrated the project with Angular 7 and the links stopped working. They are working if i include `(click)="$event.stopPropagation()"`.

Is there any reason for this behavior and can we give a global solution for this?

Comment: Hey just tested both links in my SPA (using Angular 7.2.0) and cannot reproduce it. Both working well on my machine.

Comment: When you say "the links stopped working" - what do you mean? Are there any errors you can show us?

Comment: Even after doing an upgrade to Angular 7.2.2 it continues working. Does this happen only in production (not tested on my side) or in development mode as well via `ng serve`? Do you have any output in `console` when this error occurs?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Does they not clickable anymore or not able to open it in new window or what?

Comment: This is interesting indeed, but it seems that those that have tried have been unable to reproduce it. Could you provide us with a [mcve] ?